# "Use Nodes" Button for Materials in Blender 2.8

Tags: materials, node-editor

I can't seem to find this button in Blender 2.8.:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: Blender 2.8 is smarter, it creates nodes automatically, you have to just go to node editor and adjust accordingly!

Comment: That exact button won't be there in 2.8 as there won't be render engine related to it (Internal).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Switch to the Shader Editor, in the upper-left:

[image: Shader Editor Option]

Then edit the material nodes:

[image: Node Editor]

Answer (score 5):

Blender may have added the use nodes button on the interface now..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the render engine to Eevee and the 'use nodes' button will appear.